# How to make a HTML Page in A4 paper size page(s)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

1. Essentially, I want to be able to show the HTML page in the browser, and outline the content in the dimensions of an A4 size page.
2. Also, when the HTML page is printed, it would come out as A4-sized paper pages.

```js
     <div className='w-[2480px] h-[3508px]'>
        //content here 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    div {
      width: 21cm;
      height: 29.7cm;
      background: white;
    }
    @media print {
      div {
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
      }
    }
</style>
```

You can also specify the dimensions in inches (8.27in x 11.69in) or pixels (595px x 842px).

Comment: A white background is good, but what about not-printable areas (the printer margins)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify width and height in css like this:

HTML:

```
<div className='cssPropertyA4Size'>
        //content here 
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
cssPropertyA4Size{

   width: ;//add width in pixels or percentage
   height: ;//add height in pixels or percentage

 };
```

Comment: This may work on the testprinter but it's not full proof on other printers.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to work with percentages so you'll have no problems with not-printable areas (margins) on different printers. For example

```css
/* avoid unwanted page breaks */
@media print {
  body {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  h1, h2, h3, img, a, blockquote, tr {
    max-width: 100%;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  h1, h2, h3, p {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
}

/* your page css */
@media print {
    div.view {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="view">
        Your page here
    </div>
</body>
```